# NSDate current time

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I need this result from two NSDate or etc:

First NSDate for example: 2011-02-20 00:00 AM What every the iPhone timeZone has

Sec. NSDate for example: 2011-03-20 23:59 PM What every the iPhone timeZone has

I really confuse with the implement!
I done as following:

```
NSCalendar *gCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents  *gComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

gComponents.day = gDayEventChecker;
gComponents.month = gMonthEventChecker;
gComponents.year = gYearEventChecker;
gComponents.hour = 0;
NSDate *first = [gCal dateFromComponents:gComponents];


NSCalendar *gCal2 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents  *gComponents2 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

gComponents2.day = gDayEventChecker2;
gComponents2.month = gMonthEventChecker2;
gComponents2.year = gYearEventChecker2;
gComponents2.hour = 23;
gComponents2.mintue = 59;


NSDate *sec = [gCal2 dateFromComponents:gComponents2];
```

The result is not correct!

First:  2011-02-20 01:30:00 +0000
Second: 2011-03-20 01:30:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but have a look at the method `timeIntervalSinceDate` here : [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: On terminal will written: 2011-03-20 01:30:00 +0000. I need to be: 2011-03-20 23:59:00 ANY TIMEZONE